# Ruby on rails 6.1.2 Creating posts from index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-generators, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I just started studying Rails and I need some help.

I executed the command `rails g scaffold posts title:string description:string`, and I have generated some pages and a controller.

Page `localhost:3000/posts` shows me all my posts.

Page `localhost:3000/posts/new` give me the form to create a new post.

How could I create a post from `localhost:3000/posts` page? [My code here - github](https://github.com/OlecsandrKirpa/fakesocial)

Thank you a lot!

Comment: The guides are a great first stop in your Rails journey https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 1):

When you access the page `localhost:3000/posts`, you basically are making a `GET` request to `/posts` route. To create a new element, you must make a `POST` request to the `/posts` route.
So, you need to create a form using method `POST`, or use the javascript to make a background post request on the index.

On terminal, you can exec `rails routes` to check all the routes.